# HTML Tag not closed properly

Tags: php, html

When I have code like this:

`<li <php>echo "something"</php> > aaa </li>`

My IDE/Editor does not recognize this and prompts that the start of my html tag is not properly closed. It is, however clearly closed both as a tag and tag set. How can I remove this error prompt from an IDE such as Zend Studio?

Here are other examples:

```
<input name="pagestyle" type="radio" id="pagestyle2" onclick="checkMuList()" value="2" <?php if($cfg_album_style==2) echo " checked='checked'"; ?>  />
<input type="hidden" name="mysql_username" value="<?=$_POST["mysql_username"]; ?>">
```

The code is want to decide to give a class to the tag of . So if the condition is YES , the code will give this tag a class ,but if the condition is NO,  do noting so the specific code is like that:

`<li<?php(a==b)?class="current":NULL;?>> <a href="" ><span>Hot</span></a></li>`

and the error in the Zend Studio show the next picture:(because I have no reputation to add picture, so I just share it with Dropbox)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109249235/Untitled.png

Comment: A php code block is surrounded with `<?php ...code here... ?>`.  Not `<php></php>`.

Comment: It is NEVER a good idea to expose data such as `mysql_username` to a browser or any other externally visible data.  Even a hidden input makes that data easily and immediately accessible.  Unless of course your `mysql_username` is actually just the user's username.  Even so, it does not make much sense to pass that through to another form in most cases.

Comment: yes I know <?php... ?> for php code, but problem is not this because in the template (some opensource php framework) there are some mechanisms to  switch this tag to the default php tag

Answer (score 2):

Change to this, your syntax is wrong

```
<li <?php echo "something"; ?>> aaa </li>
```

Comment: the picture of the error! see the picture: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109249235/Untitled.png

Comment: The extension of your file name is .php ?

Comment: no this is the template file with extension .html. And the template engine is build-in engine of a PHP framework

Comment: You can't use php code in a .html file, you must change to .php, so the Zend Studio error is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example, you are probably trying to accomplish something like this:

```
<li <?php if(..[condition]..) echo "class='someClass'"; ?>> aaa </li>
```

But this may be better written:

```
<li class='<?php if(..[condition]..) echo "someClass"; ?>'> aaa </li>
```

so that if you want to add other classes to the `<li>` you may without much adjustment.

In your second code example, are you missing the `/`?:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mysql_username" value="<?=$_POST["mysql_username"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: The second part of your answer isn't actually relevant to the question  here.

Comment: Noted.  I'll move it to the comments.

Comment: but the first part is not the necessary of the code. the code is want to decide to give a class to the tag of <li class>. So if the condition is YES , the code will give this tag a class ,but if the condition is NO,  do noting so the specific code is like that:      <li  <php> echo (empty($_GET['order']) || $_GET['order']=='hot')?'class="current"':NULL;</php>><a href="{:U('//',array('order'=>'hot'))}" ><span>Hot {$ts['app']['app_alias']}</span></a></li>

Comment: And I know this code is right definitely, but I want to know why Zend Studio always prompt some error for the html tag(not only Zend Studio, so other text editor can't match the tag successfully).   So is is a limit for the IDE, or it's a bad habit of coding?

Comment: I am unaware of any instance of PHP using `<php></php>` as code block delimiters, but I've been wrong before.  However, your second input lacks the closing `/`, which may be what Zend is choking on.  A self contained element like `<input ... />` always ends in `/>`